Power BI: Tab level access
Don't think this feature is available yet, but I have a Power BI report with several tabs:

Tab 1
Tab 2
Tab 3
Tab 4

Tab 4 should only be visible to a specific list of users. I know that Power BI has RLS, but it's not currently available at tab level.
Is it possible to set up a navigation button on Tab 1 that sends users to Tab 4 that can only be used by specific users? Ideally I would only need to list the users who can use that button, rather than having to specify each access for all the tabs.

Yes you are correct. Power BI does not currently support page level security features. The best way is you break report into multiple reports.
Reza Rad published a workaround in this article, so I am adjusting it to make it aligned with your need.
Create a security role to include only the users who should have access to Tab 4.
Create a measure ;
CanAccessTab4 = IF(
    USERPRINCIPALNAME() IN {"user1@example.com", "user2@example.com"},
    1, 
    0
)

Insert a button that navigates to Tab 4 and under Action settings for the button, select Page navigation and point it to Tab 4.
You can format the button visibility using the CanAccessTab4 measure. If the measure is 1, the button will be visible otherwise it will not.

Thanks Amira! How do I complete the last step of setting up the button visibility? I can't seem to find the option anywhwere
